# Page reloaded before images are pushing on firebase storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-storage

After pushing some data to firebase database, I am pushing images to firebase storage but the problem is that the page reload before that images are been posting on firebase storage.

```
function submitObject() {
    if (v.form()) {
        $('.loading').css('display','block');
        for (var image of this.Images) {
            this.imagesNames.push(image.name);
        }
        const database = firebase.database();
        database.ref('/posts').push({
            description: this.description,
            Images: this.imagesNames,
            createdAt: new Date().getTime(),
            updatedAt: '',
            dateLost: new Date(this.dateLost).getTime(),
            objectName: this.objectName,
            placeLost: this.placeLost,
            firstName: this.firstName,
            lastName: this.lastName,
            numberContact: this.phoneNumber,
            emailContact: this.email,
            postType: this.typeLost,
            uid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
        }).then(data => {
                for (var image of this.Images) {
                    uploadImages(image, data.key);
                }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            alert('Oops! Is your server disconnected?')
        }).finally(function (e) {
                $('.loading').css('display','none');
                window.location.reload()
        })
    }
}

uploadImages = async (image, idPost) => {
    var path = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(image);
    const response = await fetch(path);
    const blob = await response.blob();

    var ref = firebase.storage().ref().child("images/"+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid+"/"+idPost+"/"+image.name);
    return ref.put(blob);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning anything from the `then()` that actually uploads the data, which means that the `finally` runs before any of the uploads complete.

Luckily your `uploadImages` function returns the `UploadTask` that `put` returns, and an [`UploadTask` behaves like a promise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask#then). So you can do something like this:

```
    ...
}).then(data => {
    let uploads = this.Images.map(uploadImages(image, data.key));
    return Promise.all(uploads);
}).catch(function(error) {
    ...
```